# How to open an angularjs page as a popup from another angularjs page

Tags: cakephp-2.0, angularjs

I have 2 CakePHP pages. Both of them use angularjs. Here's a snippet.

/items/items.ctp

```
<div id="ng-app" ng-app>`
    <div ng-controller="ItemController">
        <a href="#" ng-click="showAddPopup">Add</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

the function showAddPopup is defined as follows

```
$scope.showAddPopup = function() {
    $.colorbox({href:'/items/add/' + $scope.order.id,open:true,close : "x", onClosed:function(){}});
}
```

/items/add.ctp

```
<div id="ng-app" ng-app>`
    <div ng-controller="AddController">
        <h2>{{order.label}}<h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, when I click on the add link from items view, I get a popup with the contents of add.ctp. But the problem is that instead of showing order label say 'My Order', the h2 tag is showing `{{order.label}}`

When I open add view from a page that doesn't use angularjs I get a proper result.  What am I doing wrong. Please help. I have already wasted many days on this.

Comment: Have you tried putting this in a directive?  Directives can load templates themselves (which would be compiled by Angular) and you can use colorbox's 'inline' or 'html' options instead of 'href'.  See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iB7hfvqyZpg&feature=plcp

Comment: Isn't this because of nested ng-apps? According to docs you can't have more then one ng-app in the single document [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp). So when you open the popup from the angular app you have two ng-apps on a single page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe opening the colorbox with setting iframe could be the solution, if the problem is nested ng-apps.

```
$.colorbox({inline:false; iframe:true;href:'/items/add/'...});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap then [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) would be a great choice for above scenario